# Changing my OpenID on StackOverflow without losing my questions/ratings

Tags: support, openid

How do I change my OpenID on StackOverflow without losing my questions/ratings and settings?

My Yahoo! OpenID path has changed and I'd like to update my profile to match, but can't seem to change the OpenID path anywhere.

Comment: belongs on meta.

Answer (score 4):

how to change your openid

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/we-now-support-multiple-openids/